# Not able to click on SignOut button

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

need your help!
I am not able to click on 'Sign Out', here is the snapshot from Firebug:

```
<li class="dropdown open">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li class="dropdown-header">email_id@xyz.com</li>
<li class="signout">
<form id="form0" class="" method="post" action="/_Account/Logout">
<input type="hidden" value="mkEfSz6-X9flSbOQ6IA39rVPnHnX6gethyjNrisgAcWerf0QL7oaL1zaTFC5j9omCdvfTtjEICuRqpuPjIiiHmnog5EOBMeOHkXD7ccphD8d6BISw46JmAYfm5ZrMksC0oe91g2" name="__RequestVerificationToken">
<input class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Sign Out">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Have tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/ul[2]/li/ul/li[2]")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Sign Out']")).click();
```

this as well (not sure if this is right):

```
Select DropdownList = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form0']/input[2]")));
DropdownList.selectByVisibleText("Sign Out");
```

Comment: what error do you get? can you find the element at all?

Comment: well for the first try, I get no error, it just clicks on user icon (which has my email id and Sign Out) as options.                                                    For 2nd try, it throws: Element should have been "select" but was "input"
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46'

Comment: yes. it shows that it has clicked on the sign out, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Did you try ? `driver.findElement(By.classname("signout")).click();`

Comment: Thanks Helping Hand.. tried, didn't work.

Comment: Does your form is within iframe?

Comment: Can you share more of the code you are running and more of the HTML document? With the info you provided, the xpaths are correct for the HTML example, so there is probably another issue in the code or something else in the HTML that is causing you a headache.

Answer (score 0):

Try just like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xapth("//form[contains(@id, 'form0')]/input[contains(@class, 'btn')]")).click;
```

Comment: Can you please help! what has to be written for driver here.. WebElement yourElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/ul[2]/li/ul/li[2]"));

         IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver(...??)
         js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", yourElement);

Comment: I am sorry, can't get it right, I am using above code in a class file (not main). IwebDriver Driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Webelement yourElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/ul[2]/li/ul/li[2]"));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", yourElement); it shows something wrong with 'IWebDriver', 'IJavaScriptExecutor' and 'yourElement'

Comment: What language you are using to write this code , java ?

Comment: Okay I have changed my code to java it's a little bit different syntax now.

Comment: I don't see any tag "iframe"

Answer (score 0):

The element seems to be hidden so that's your first hurdle but try the below and see if that works.  You may have to go up (or down) another level to get it to work.
ps. I haven't run the code so watch out for any errors.

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[class='signout'] class[value='Sign Out']")).click();

Comment: Thanks Ciene, it didn't work, returned this error: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"li[class='signout'] class[value='Sign Out']"}
Command duration or timeout: 10.12 seconds

Comment: is it in a separate form? can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I tried, since I am new to this forum, requires some 10 reputation to post screens. I only see 1 form id="form0"

Comment: i made a mistake earlier can you try this again `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[class='signout'] class[value='Sign Out']")).click();` or this `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[class='signout'] > form[id='form0'] class[value='Sign Out']")).click();` or this `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form[id='form0'] input[value='Sign Out']")).click();`

Comment: A little difficult without a screen as i suspect the form is causing the issue.  Try using Selenium IDE selector.

Comment: Take screen using LightShot app and give us the link. Or just upload your screen anywhere and give us the link!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are specifying the element correctly but let's try a CSS Selector.

```
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Sign Out']")).click();
```

If that doesn't work, try this just to see if there is another element that it's finding by accident. The return here should be 1.

```
    System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[value='Sign Out']")).size());
```

Is there a `SELECT` dropdown near this Sign Out button? I have this hunch that Selenium is trying to click on your `INPUT` tag but it's somehow clicking a `SELECT` tag. Maybe it's not visible or something???

Let's also check to see if this element is within an `IFRAME`. What does this return? Hopefully 0.

```
    System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("iframe input[value='Sign Out']")).size());
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, tried all. 2nd line returned 1, 3rd line of code returned 0, but it didn't click on SignOut.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do much more without access to the page or more HTML.